Best Practices for Caching a Paginated Blog Search Results Page with Varnish
How should a blog search results page be cached, considering it returns a list of 10 items with pagination (GET ?query=<search_term>&page=<number>) to navigate to the next page? What cache control headers should the backend send to Varnish, and what are the best practices for managing cache in this scenario? Any recommendations for efficiently handling caching with pagination in Varnish?

There are 2 things to address based on your question:

How long to cache such a search result
How to identify search results in the cache (and have a good hit rate)

Cache-Control
The Cache-Control header you need depends on a number of factors, but let's just assume you have a cache invalidation mechanism built into your code, that can remove outdated objects from the cache.
In that case, you can set longer TTLS. You can also set different TTLs for Varnish and for the browser.
Here's an example:
Cache-Control: public, max-age=600, s-maxage=3600, stale-while-revalidate=86400

This header will instruct Varnish to cache the object for an hour (s-maxage=3600), and gives the browser the opportunity to cache for 600 seconds (max-age=600).
After an hour the object will inspire but because of stale-while-revalidate=86400, the object will be kept around in the cache for an extra day (at most) after the expiration of the object to serve stale content while asynchronous revalidation takes place.
This means that old content is deliberately returned to guarantee decent performance, while at the same time a newer version of that content is fetched from the backend.
These TTL values aren't really best practices as such, but they give you the ability to cache for quite a long time. And that's fine, because we assume we can purge items from the cache when changes in the backend system occur.
Improving the hit rate
The second question is related to identifying objects in the cache.
By default, Varnish uses the complete URL to identify objects in the cache. Query string parameters also count. You use them to display search results.
That's why it's important to sanitize them to ensure a good hit rate.
One piece of advice is to validate certain values in VCL before the cache is hit. Quick example:
if(req.url ~ "\?query=[^&]+&page=.*$" && req.url !~ "&page=[^0-9]+") {
    return(synth(400));
}

This quick & dirty code will ensure the value of the page parameter is numeric, and will return a synthetic HTTP 400 response if it isn't.
You could also validate the value of the query parameter and filter out bogus search terms.
I would also apply the regsuball() function on the URL to remove unwanted query string parameters that users might add. These will cause cache misses and allow malicious users to poison the cache.
This technique can also be used to trim off marketing parameters (Google, Hubspot & others), as explained in one of our tutorials.
And finally, I would recommend, sorting query string parameters alphabetically to improve you hit rate and avoid unwanted cache variations. This is also explained in that tutorial. It leverages set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);.
